# Python crashing when calling pyopencl.get_platforms()

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I cannot call `pyopencl.get_platforms()` or `.create_some_context()` without python crashing.
The exception in the dump file is "The threat tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access"

Any ideas?

Specs:
Windows 7 64 
Python 2.7.3
Cuda 5.5

Comment: Try running the script as administrator. That should do the trick.

Comment: I am running as administrator